# How to show LOC in my project's dashboard?

Tags: sonarqube

"Lines of Code" is blank in SonarQube's dashboard for my project. This project does not have any bugs and the unit test coverage is 80%.

[image: screenshot of SonarQube's dashboard for my project]

How can I show the lines of code for this .net project in my SonarQube Dashboard?

I'm using sonar enterprise edition and sonar runner 2.8. I have excluded some folders and used some of this configurations in my jenkins job as well: `sonar.sources=Source,sonar.language=cs,sonar.sourceEncoding=‌​UTF-8`. I'm using open cover as code coverage.

Comment: As an enterprise customer, you should definitely consider to contact the official support!

Comment: If you browse your project's code, do you see any .net sources?

Comment: Which version of SonarQube enterprise edition do you use? Probably 5.6, right?

Comment: @slartidan Please do not use inline code formatting for things that are not code. "Lines of Code" is not code, so it should not have been formatted that way.